# Why does paginate_links() reload the entire page? and can you make it reload only a specific div?

Tags: paginate-links

Beginner here; apologise for any obvious mistakes.

I have a post list on my homepage showing 3 posts at a time and using `paginate_links()`.

When I click on page2 or next in the paginate_links(), it reloads the entire homepage(and scrolls to the top of page.

Need to scroll down back to post list) and then the page2 of the post list is shown.

My homepage has a lot of other content; so is there a way for `paginate_links()` to work by reloading only the post lists instead of the entire page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pageinate_links` is a function that retrieves paginated link for archive post pages.

So yes - there are links. And links works exactly this way - if you click on it, you will go to the url that is connected with that link - so the page will get reloaded.

If you want the link to cause a partial reload of only one div (or other container), you'll have to write your own code, that will:

1. Prevent the link reloading the page when clicked.
2. Send AJAX request to the server and obtain new content of that container.
3. Replace the content of container with the new content received from server.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Could you point me to a guide or a thread as to how I could achieve this?

Comment: No problem. Which part needs additional guidance?

Comment: I'm new to this. Tried looking around, and couldn't find much about it's implementation in pagination. Could you show me how to implement your answer for my div?